# Excel #REF! error when applying working formula to external file

Tags: excel-formula

So the below formula is correctly applied to the below image:

```
=ABS(INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york",A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )))/(LEFT(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york",A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1))-(RIGHT(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york",A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )))/(LEFT(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york",A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1)), LEN("(base)")) = "(base)")*100)
```

However, when I try to apply this to an external file, I get the #REF! error, despite the data being exactly the same.

```
=ABS(INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH("new york",’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, 0)):INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH(1E+99,’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!B:B )))/(LEFT(INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH("new york",’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, 0)):INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH(1E+99,’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!B:B )), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1))-(RIGHT(INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH("new york",’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, 0)):INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH(1E+99,’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!B:B )))/(LEFT(INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH("new york",’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, 0)):INDEX(‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!A:A, MATCH(1E+99,’C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’!B:B )), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1)), LEN("(base)")) = "(base)")*100)
```

Does anyone know what is causing the error and how I can fix it?

[Simplified data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwTdr.png)

Comment: You need to have a worksheet open to reference it in formulas

Answer (score 1):

You will have to try as below,

Instead of using `‘C:\Path\[File]Sheet1’`, use `[Book1]Sheet2`.

Eg: [name_of_your_file]name_of_the_sheet

```
=ABS(INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH("new york",[Book1]Sheet2!A:A, 0)):INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH(1E+99,[Book1]Sheet2!B:B )))/(LEFT(INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH("new york",[Book1]Sheet2!A:A, 0)):INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH(1E+99,[Book1]Sheet2!B:B )), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1))-(RIGHT(INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH("new york",[Book1]Sheet2!A:A, 0)):INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH(1E+99, [Book1]Sheet2!B:B )))/(LEFT(INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH("new york",[Book1]Sheet2!A:A, 0)):INDEX([Book1]Sheet2!A:A, MATCH(1E+99, [Book1]Sheet2!B:B )), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1)), LEN("(base)")) = "(base)")*100)
```

Comment: My understanding is that this would only work for files that are open.  I tested this regardless and it still gave me the REF error.  The issue seems to be related to defining the array in the index formula, but I don't understand why...

Comment: Yes, however you will have to open the worksheets after the final edition you have done. Though it says #REF!, it will get the actual value for the cell once you open the relevant 2nd sheet you referred to. So, carry on your work and finally open the other sheet, otherwise Excel has no access to get the data from a closed file.